# Compare character arrays to be printed

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int i, a = 0, j;
    int num[26]={};
    char alp[26], ch[100]={'s', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' };

    //Initialize array alp[] with alphabets a to z.
    for(int i=97; i <(97+26) ; i++)
        alp[i-97]=i;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {

        for (j = 0; ch[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (alp[i] == ch[j])
                num[i] = a++;
        }

        cout << endl << string(5, ' ') << alp[i] << string(5, ' ');

        if (num[i])
            cout << num[i] << endl;
        else cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is no compilation error. However, when i print, i get garbage values (num[i]). Basically i am comparing an array of characters with an array of alphabets, then printing a table with the number of alphabets(alp array, already initialized with all alphabets a to z) the ch array contains.

Comment: Where do you initialize a (give it a start value)?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you really want help create mcve

Comment: int i, a=0, j;int num[26];

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31057618/edit) your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: And where do you set initial values of num array to 0?

Comment: I don't think "alphabet" means what you think it means.

Comment: I already initialized alp array to contain all the alphabets from a to z. sure of that.

Comment: Refer to my previous comment.

Comment: _"sure of that"_ Nope. We can't just take your word for it, especially as you're the one with the problem. That's why you are expected to post an SSCCE. You were informed of this upon signing up to this site.

Comment: alright, il edit it.

Comment: Offtopic but it may help you creating better code. You should declare variables in the scope in which they are used. The index variable in a for-loop may be declared as for (int i = 0; i < last; ++i).

Comment: @MichielUitHetBroek thats a matter of style and purpose. When I write algorithms with several counters and/or other coordinates, I often like to initialize all variables in the head, commenting the meaning of interesting values to watch. Just as in school, when you solved your math problem, first writing down what you can say about the parameters and the free variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array `num` is not initialized so it gets garbage values. If you want to initialize it with 0 change your code:

```
int num[26] = {};
```

For the purpose of the question, the problem becomes clearer, though less effective, when you initialize each value you use in the loop

```
int i, a = 0, j;
int num[26];
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    num[i]=0;
...
```

Of course the initialization is the shorter and cleaner solution.

Comment: _"If you really want help create mcve"_ \*provides help anyway\* o.O

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They might have figured out a solution after posting the comment

Comment: @KABoissonneault: The point is that the OP should post an MCVE before being deserving of help. Slava has suggested the OP can have it both ways! Most peculiar.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit He did not provide enough information in the beginning, he changed the question and provided it later. If he put mcve he would get the answer instantly.

Comment: It's still not an MCVE though.

Comment: come on, just put a main around it and set some `char ch[] = "hello, world!";` and the `alp`(habet).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit before I complained when somebody provided help for a person who posted code on pastebin. I said that you should not help to person who breaks rules. I got obstruction that I am annoying people who provide real help.

Comment: @Slava: Pffft no you were absolutely right. Crack on!

Comment: Sorry guys, im really new to this. I got it though. Thanks to everyone, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @NabilMustafa there is nothing to be sorry about if you listen and follow.

Comment: Will be more attentive next time :)